# Getting Information from other program for my java application

Tags: java

I need that my java application be able to get some information(tables , strings, etc) from others programs(.exe programs). I don't know the programming language that the other program is using. I know a guy here at work that did it using delphi, but i need a java application. I was doing some research and i found JNA, is this the way to go? In his application folder i found the following .dlls : **apigid32 ,asycfilt, Comcat, msstkprp, Msvbvm60, Oleaut32,Olepro32,Vb6stkit.** . Any of these dlls is doing the communication between his delphi application and the program ?

Ty for your help.

Comment: You have many ways to communicate two (or more) programs: by database, by files (text and/or binary files), by TCP/IP or UDP socket connections, through calls between both using Web Services (or another technology over TCP/IP like Corba), using pipes... and more and more. You should make your design based on this info.

Comment: It's called JNI, and I'd put it last in order of preference after each of @LuiggiMendoza's suggestions. Only do it when you absolutely have to.

Comment: Not sure why people downvoted this question. It's a valid question. Rather unusual and presents insane danger, but still valid.

Comment: The program company provides an ActiveX control to do the link with her application and get tables info,etc. Now i only need to know how to use the .ocx file provided(is this the right extension for the ActiveX? ) with java.

Answer (score -1):

The best option (on a local base) would be to have the other program output the strings, tables, arrays, etc to a file (I recommend .txt files for an easy read) and have Java load them from the file

ex. code (Java)
Import statement:

```
import java.io.*
```

The code you need to write a string to a file:

```
BufferedWriter outStream= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt", true));
outStream.newLine();
outStream.write(outputString);
outStream.close();
```

Comment: -1 for "cannot use DLL files". It can. It is generally a bad idea (depending on the usage), but it can.

Comment: Fixed, although I thought Java could not use DLL files for file IO without being redundant (you would already have java.io imported, and it is easier to just use methods in that class)

Comment: Well, yes. It might be redundant, rather insane, but still - it's possible.